# How can I replace a text between two characters (Lua)

Tags: string, text, replace, lua

I wanna do a replacement for `myString = "This is __an example__, it's the coolest thing ever!"`
I want to replace the first __ with `<span style="bla bla bla">` and the second one with `</span>`

I have no idea on how I could make that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try also this code:

```
myString = "This is __an example__, it's the coolest thing ever!"
myString = myString:gsub("__(.-)__", "<span style='bla bla bla'>%1</span>")
```

Comment: Would that work for more than one "instance" of `__TEXT__` or would the max limit be also 1

Comment: @iCodeTits, `gsub` means *global substitution*, so it works for all instances. To restrict  to the first instance, add `,1`at the end of the call, as in Rithik's answer.

Comment: But that's the thing, I need to replace the first `__` with `x` and the second `__` with `y`, but wanted to do it more than once

Comment: @iCodeTits, add to the question more examples of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Ex. `__THIS IS A SPAN__ and this is not, while __THIS IS ANOTHER SPAN__ and this is not, again!`, you get me?

Comment: @iCodeTits, my code works fine in that case: it replaces both instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myString = "This is __an example__, it's the coolest thing ever!"
myString = myString:gsub("__", "<span style='bla bla bla'>",1)
myString = myString:gsub("__", "</span>",1)
```